# How to compute such a limit?

Tags: calculus

Knowing $f(x,y) = 2x^2 +3y^2 -7x +15y$,  one simply proves $$|f(x,y)|\leq 5(x^2+y^2)+22 \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$$ How can I use this info to compute
$$ \lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)} \frac{f(x,y) - 2(x^2+y^2)^{1/4}}{(x^2+y^2)^{1/4}}\;\;\; ?$$

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This can be done quite easily if you convert to polar coordinates.

We convert

$$lim_{x, y \to (0, 0)} \frac{2x^2 + 3y^2 - 7x + 15y - 2(x^2 + y^2)^{\frac{1}{4}}}{(x^2 + y^2)^{\frac{1}{4}}}$$

turns into

$$lim_{r \to 0} \>\> \frac{2r^2\cos^2 \theta + 3r^2 \sin^2 \theta - 7r \cos \theta + 15 r \sin \theta - 2 \sqrt{r}}{\sqrt{r}}$$

$$lim_{r \to 0} \> \>2 r^{\frac{3}{2}}\cos^2 \theta + 3 r^{\frac{3}{2}} \sin^2 \theta -7 \sqrt{r} \cos \theta + 15 \sqrt{r} \sin \theta - 2 $$

$$= -2$$

Answer (score 0):

Approach limit with $y = mx$
then 
$$
\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)} \frac{f(x,y) - 2(x^2+y^2)^{1/4}}{(x^2+y^2)^{1/4}} = 
$$
$$
\lim_{x\to0} \frac{x(2x +3m^2x -7 +15m)}{x^{1/2}(1+m^2)^{1/4}} - 2 = 
$$
$$
\lim_{x\to0} \frac{x^{1/2}( -7 +15m)}{(1+m^2)^{1/4}} - 2 = -2
$$

Comment: Unfortunately this only works along lines. There are nonlinear paths to the origin, and there are examples where the limits along all lines exist and agree, but the limit itself does not exist.

Comment: But if the limit exists it will be always the same regardless of the path

Comment: Sure, but this doesn't show the limit exists

Comment: The question asked to compute it, not to show its existence, it was assumed that it already exist